# Autenticar por SMS

Tags: android, sms

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para autenticar um cadastro enviando SMS para o número de celular do usuário? E quais são as empresas que prestam esse serviço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é muito relativo, você mesmo pode fazer isso.
Segue um **fluxo**:

1. Usuário cadastra o numero celular.
2. Servidor recebe o cadastro e envia o sms com o token para o dispositivo.
3. O dispositivo ler a SMS Recebida, extrai o token e envia para o serviço de autenticação. (Enviando para o servidor executar uma validação em cima do token recebido).

Como podemos fazer isso?

**Opções:**

**1. Você pode implementar o envio de SMS no seu servidor.**

Será necessário o uso de um microcontrolador, como arduino e um modulo de rede GSM + um chip GSM com créditos.(No Brasil, você pode utilizar planos de operadoras que trabalham com SMS ilimitado por um valor fixo).

Tutorial para envio de SMS com o arduino: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesSendSMS

Depois disso, você terá q integrar o seu Service(WebService com o arduino), para assim fazer o envio das mensagens para os dispositivos cadastrados.

**2. Você pode integrar o seu servidor para utilizar algum serviço de envio de SMS.**
   ex fornecidos por @RenatoTavares com algumas complementações:

> 1. www.bulksms.com
> 2. www.clickatell.com
> 3. www.twilio.com
> 4. http://www.solutionsinfini.com/clients.php
> 5. http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/
> 6. http://www.vfirst.com/

Link com um tutorial de como fazer isso que você está desejando, contratando alguma empresa para o envio do SMS: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/

obs: Em ambos os casos, será necessário um WebService para o dispositivo se comunicar com o servidor, fazendo com que a SMS com o token seja enviado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu criei um software em python que se comunica com modens 3G e fazem o envio do SMS. Foi bem tranquilo, sofri muito para achar um modem bom, mas o software foi fácil. Mas empresas pagas tem:

- www.bulksms.com
- www.clickatell.com
- www.twilio.com